# Unsorted List inside a unsorted list created with DOM

Tags: javascript

So I have creted an UL list with Javascript, but the hierarchy wont get right... And I really dont know how to embeed dem with each other...

This is the look Im strungling for.

```
<div class="dice-toolbar-wrapper">
<ul>
<li class="add"></li>
<li class="remove"></li>
 <li class="roll"></li>
 <li>
 <ul class="dice-toolbar-counter-wrapper">
 <li class="zero"></li>
 <li class="zero"></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

This is how I create the list.

```
  dice_toolbar_wrapper_close = createElementWithClass('div', 'dice-toolbar-wrapper');
    outerDiv.appendChild(dice_toolbar_wrapper_close);
    document.getElementById("page-content-wrapper");

     add_remove_roll = createElementWithOutClass('ul');
    dice_toolbar_wrapper_close.appendChild(add_remove_roll);
    document.getElementById("dice-content-wrapper");
```

But this is what I get after rendering the page.

```
<div class="dice-toolbar-wrapper">
<ul>
<li class="add"></li>
<li class="remove"></li>
<li class="roll"></li>
</ul>
<ul class="dice-toolbar-counter-wrapper">
<li class="zero"></li>
</ul>
</ul>
</div>
```

Any tips on how i can change the li tags ?

Thanks

Comment: I hope `var createElementWithOutClass = document.createElement.bind(document);` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're dealing with the DOM, you're not dealing with *markup* as you seem to be thinking (from the variable name `dice_toolbar_wrapper_close`), you're dealing with *objects*. There are no "open" and "close" tags, there are elements.

So to create a `ul`:

```
var ul = document.createElement('ul');
```

To put an `li` inside it:

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
ul.appendChild(li);
```

And it's **exactly** the same if you want to create an inner `ul` and put that in the `li`:

```
var innerUl = document.createElement('ul');
li.appendChild(innerUl);
```

Complete example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/arasog/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/arasog/1/edit)

```
(function() {

  var outerUL, li, innerUL, thirdLI, index;

  outerUL = document.createElement('ul');
  for (index = 0; index < 5; ++index) {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = "Outer li #" + index;
    if (index === 2) {
      thirdLI = li;
    }
    outerUL.appendChild(li);
  }

  innerUL = document.createElement('ul');
  for (index = 0; index < 3; ++index) {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = "Inner li #" + index;
    innerUL.appendChild(li);
  }
  thirdLI.appendChild(innerUL);

  document.body.appendChild(outerUL);

})();
```

Comment: I kinda get what you're saying, with the open and close tags.. Need to analyze the code you send me for a while.

Thank you, will tell you soon if i get it ;)

Comment: @Dymond: Think of it like a string. When you're writing a string literal in a source file, you type an opening quote, the contents of the string, and a closing quote; that's like the start and end tags in HTML files. But the thing your code is interacting with in memory is an object, not an opening quote, content, and a closing quote.